# An error occurred while loading the PDF document

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I would like you to help me with this problem.

I have some time working with a project in Laravel 5.6. This week I installed the barryvdh / laravel-dompdf package via composer as indicated in the documentation.
I added the respective service provider in the config \ app.php file.

When trying to use the package for the first time I get the following error in Chrome:
"An error occurred while loading the PDF document"

When I download the document and visualize it with a text editor, I realize that the only thing that is wrong with the file is that it lacks the first line:% PDF-1.3. When adding said line manually the document is "fixed".

To continue testing, I installed a new laravel project, and then I installed the package and created a route with the same code from the previous project. To my surprise, this project does load the PDF document in Chrome.

Please give me some idea of ​​what things I can review.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the barryvdh / laravel-dompdf package, because the problem still persists with PDF files that were not created with dompdf.

I really appreciate any ideas you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it.
The cause of the problem was that the `config/app.php` configuration file did not have the `<?php` line at startup, and this was what caused the problem.